# Android Firebase java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqo()Z in class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing this error, and I don't know what's going wrong.

FirebaseDatabase not initializing giving this error. All the dependencies are same as per firebase doc, but still getting this error.

App always crash when firebase database is initialize.

Does anyone know the solution because I tried every thing but all in vein.

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqo()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.hypertrack.uber_consumer-DvUezTpoT5o5n6I7J2WLgg==/base.apk)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source:128)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source:22)
```

Here is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abc"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

//HyperTrack: HyperTrack library
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://hypertrack-android-sdk.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/'
    }
}


ext {
    supportVersion = '27.1.0'
    playServicesVersion = '11.8.0'
    butterKnifeVersion = '8.8.1'
    glideVersion = '3.7.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"

    //Custom ProgressBar/ loader
    implementation 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.5.0'

    //implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'

    //ButterKnife
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterKnifeVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterKnifeVersion"

    //Firbase auth for login
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$playServicesVersion"

    //Firebase Realtime database for getting Customer trips data : models.Trip
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$playServicesVersion"

    //Fetch image
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1"
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'

    //Google Direction Api: Displaying route from source-destimation
    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.2.9'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'

    //HyperTrack: HyperTrack library
    implementation('com.hypertrack:android:0.7.39@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}

//HyperTrack: FCM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$playServicesVersion"
compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.2.9'
```

to

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"
```

And don't also forget to add:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
```

Which is now mandatory. As of the [June 12th release](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) of the Firebase SDK, you must explicitly include `firebase-core`:

> Your app gradle file now has to explicitly list `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` as a dependency for Firebase services to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy.